# Security of String Encryption in C# Obfuscation

Tags: c#, encryption, obfuscation

**Disclaimer:** I'm perfectly aware that a client-side program will never be safe from a dedicated reverse engineer.

Mostly out of personal curiosity, I've been learning about "obfuscation" techniques for C# applications. It seems that a popular technique is "string encryption", which appears to encrypt the string constants in the software and decrypt them for use later. This makes them not appear properly in decompilers like Reflector (please correct me if this is wrong).

If this is true, and you only see an encrypted version of the string in Reflector, what needs to be done (i.e. how difficult is it) to work around this and get the decrypted string? Obviously it must be possible or the application wouldn't be able to do it, but just how much of a deterrent would it be?

Comment: You already have the decompiler.  Just look for the decryption function.

Comment: Most of them are simple string XOR's.. trivial to reverse even without the decryption function.

Comment: Salamander supposedly completes string decryption.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with C# obfuscators, but the Java obfuscators I've looked at (Stringer, Allatori, Zelix Klassmaster, JFuscator) were pretty bad. Usually, I can reverse engineer the encryption algorithm after a day or two, and then I can deobfuscate all apps protected by the same obfuscator version and other versions usually only require a slight tweak.

Note that this is for purely static analysis, to figure out the algorithm and write a script that decrypts it without executing any code. If your goal is to just decrypt things quickly, it's a lot easier to simply execute the decryption function. The good obfuscators have a call context check so you can't do it directly, but it's a simple matter to find and edit out the check. This could potentially be done in only a couple minutes.

Obviously, there are ways to make reverse engineering much harder, but they aren't done in practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the encrypted strings in your application, then you also *have the decryption key embedded in your application*.

So, a moderately determined person could use a debugger to step through the decryption code to retrieve the key, and then decrypt all other strings in your application with the flick of a wrist.

Answer (score 0):

How much time it would need to understand manually
depends on the general obfuscation level,
ie. if there is a method decrypt which can be called just like that...
with compiling and all probably <1min

The other, simple way: Recompile with debug information, set a breakpoint,
execute the program and just read the string in VS
("simple" depends what is necessary to get to this code part)

Answer (score 0):

I only recently learned about the secureString class. I am sure it is not a total solution, but in combination with other techniques, it might help. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> The value of an instance of SecureString is automatically encrypted when the instance is initialized or when the value is modified. 
>   Note that SecureString has no members that inspect, compare, or convert the value of a SecureString. The absence of such members helps protect the value of the instance from accidental or malicious exposure.